Magento 2 - Filterable product attribute in layered navigation visibility?
Is filterable product attribute visible in layered navigation in magento ONLY when all products have value set for that attribute?
I have filterable select attribute which is not required and it is shown in layered navigation on search page only when I select value in that attribute on all products. If there is a product left where I didnt set the value for that attribute, its not shown on frontend in filter.
Thanks!
